# Cycles Emission Render Layer Issue - Emission Objects appear in final render as if they have xray

Tags: cycles-render-engine

This is a resubmitted question as my previous one was buried and forgotten.

I will describe this as simply as I can.

I have 1 cube and 2 icospheres in my scene. The cube is on layer 1. The isospheres are on layer 2. I have one icosphere in front of the cube and one behind it. However in my final render, the icosphere behind the cube appears in front of cube, as though it has x-ray checked.

I realize there are many things that would work here, but I am doing a very complicated animation and all of the quick fixes for this will not work. Masks, material and object indexes will not work. Alpha over is also out because in the animation, objects will be inside of other objects. Image 1 is a cube with two icospheres. The dark grey is the cube. The blue ones are the icospheres. The cube is on layer 1. The icospheres are on layer 2. I want to blur layer 2 and only layer 2. The blur does show up in image 1, but as you can see the left icosphere, which is behind the cube is visible. That is the problem. Image 3 is my node setup.

Here is the .blend file , https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/791/

[image: Image 1]
[image: Image 2]
[image: Image 3]

Please help, Thanks

Comment: Please place images in your question to clarify your question. 3D View and Outliner view, Nodes.  I think the images will help so that your question  is less likely to be, as you wrote above, [buried and forgotten].

Comment: Please edit the original question and do not duplicate posts.

Comment: Very sorry, but this site is quite confusing to me.

Comment: @RichardBrockJr. Welcome to the site :) It does take some getting used to if you're more accustomed to traditional forums and the like. Perhaps the [tour] will help clarify some things.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a bug, it's the expected behaviour. What you need is to use the "Z combine" node, that will combine the z values of both the render layers. In my example I put only Layer 1 into render Layer 1, and only Layer 2 in Render Layer 2. I also increased the blur to 50.

[image]